# Multiple dex file google play services lib error in lib project

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I have made one library project which has support for bluecats for location tracking. In that project I added `google play services.jar` file location getting location using `map api v2`. I added this library project in my second project where I am implementing `google map`. See below screen shots.

This is my library project build path snap.
[image]

Here is my project build path in which I am using Map and above mentioned library project.
[image]

when I am running my project It will showing

```
Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command$1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
google-play-services.jar
gcm.jar
```

from your main project. these jars are already in the library project. so you do not need to add them again in your main project.

also try to remove the

```
android-support-v4.jar
```

from your main project. and in your library project 
remove

```
android-support-v13.jar
```

and add

```
android-support-v4.jar
```

Now clean your project and try to run it. hope this will help.

**Edit:**

you should avoid to use `gcm.jar`. because, google recommend us to use GCM feature using `google-play-services.jar`. now GCM is included in `google-play-services.jar`. use latest `google-play-services.jar` and remove `gcm.jar` from your project. and sure, you have to change the import(s) for GCM if you use `google-play-services.jar` for GCM rather than `gcm.jar`

Comment: But when I am removing google-play-services.jar and gcm.jar from main project then it will showing error on GoogleMap.

Comment: is the error is still showing after you added the library project to your main project??

Comment: No But then SupportMapFragment show me error and It will ask me for add android-support-v4.jar in build path.

Comment: remove `android-support-v4.jar` from your main project and add it to your library project. this will solve it. and from you library project remove the `android-support-v13.jar`. and don't forget to clean your both project